# What is the alpha attribute in a CanvasRenderingContext2D?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) says:

> alpha: Boolean that indicates if the canvas contains an alpha channel.
>   If set to false, the browser now knows that the backdrop is always
>   opaque, which can speed up drawing of transparent content and images
>   then.

Sounds straight forward, but I am still not very clear what exactly this attribute is doing.

It says "When false the browser knows the backdrop is always opaque". Now if I later set `canvasElem.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,200,200,0.5)";`
I still get a transparent canvas background and it still computes alpha.

Comment: on which browser are you? In supporting browsers (chrome, FF and Opera) this will produce an opaque canvas as in no pixels will have alpha values below 255, so it starts all black. https://jsfiddle.net/gzoL7kyx/

Comment: @Kaiido, I messed up earlier. Yes, I do get a black backdrop now. It was simple after all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is quite straight froward.
In supporting browsers (according to the page you linked to Chrome, Firefox and Opera), this will create a context where no pixel can have transparency.

This means that it will start all black, and that all alpha blendings that could happen would be made against these first black fully opaque pixels.

So this also means that you wouldn't be able to see this CSS backround color anyway, which tends me to think that you tried on a non-supporting browser, or that you didn't called it correctly.

```js
ctx= canvas.getContext('2d', {alpha:false});
ctx.fillStyle= 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I get it now.  This page also added to my confusion earlier: https://www.rgraph.net/blog/the-canvas-getcontext-function-now-with-alpha-attribute.html